# modifying list holding tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I have a list with tuples in it looking like this:

```
my_list = (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', [(u'1', u'text1'), (u'2', u'text2'), (u'3', u'text3'), (u'4', u'text4'), (u'5', u'text5')])
```

I'd like to iterate over `my_list[3]` and copy the rest so I would get n lists looking like this:

```
(u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'1', u'text1')
(u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'2', u'text2')
(u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'3', u'text3')
(u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'4', u'text4')
(u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'5', u'text5')
```

I have tried using a for loop but I end up this:

```
((u'code', u'somet text', u'integer'), (u'1', u'text1'))
((u'code', u'somet text', u'integer'), (u'2', u'text2'))
((u'code', u'somet text', u'integer'), (u'3', u'text3'))
((u'code', u'somet text', u'integer'), (u'4', u'text4'))
((u'code', u'somet text', u'integer'), (u'5', u'text5'))
```

Also, the code I am using does not feel very pythonic at all, `my_list[3]` can differ in length.

```
my_list = (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', [(u'1', u'text1'), (u'2', u'text2'), (u'3', u'text3'), (u'4', u'text4'), (u'5', u'text5')])
my_modified_list = my_list[0:3]
last_part_of_my_list = my_list[3]


for i in last_part_of_my_list:
    print (my_modified_list, i)
```

Comment: @pstatix in Python index start from `0`, so `my_list[3]` is tuple(...).

Comment: @godaygo That was my fault, counted wrong...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using simple tuple concatenation with `+`:

```
nlists = [my_list[:-1] + tpl for tpl in my_list[-1]]

[(u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'1', u'text1'),
 (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'2', u'text2'),
 (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'3', u'text3'),
 (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'4', u'text4'),
 (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'5', u'text5')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly unpack your tuple:
`a,b,c,d = my_list`
This, of course, assumes 4 elements exactly to your tuple or you'll get an exception.
Then iterate over d:

`for d1,d2 in d:
    print('({},{},{},{},{})'.format(a,b,c,d1,d2))`

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over and join them with the `operator+`:

```
fixed = my_list[:3] # this becomes (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer')
new_list = [fixed + x for x in my_list[3]] # list comprehension to build new list
```

You must be careful in your terminology. You call your variable `my_list` but the `()` around the entire content of the variable makes it a `tuple` not `list`. Your `my_list[3]` however is a `list` of `tuples`. Both these containers support the `operator+` for concatenation.

So using this solution (which is *Pythonic* and works with n-sized `my_list[3]`), you can read it as:

"`new_list` is a list of the `fixed` variable plus the current element for each element in `my_list[3]`"

With your current data you get a `list` (again, with `[]`):

```
[(u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'1', u'text1'),
 (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'2', u'text2'),
 (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'3', u'text3'),
 (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'4', u'text4'),
 (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', u'5', u'text5')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
my_list = (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', [(u'1', u'text1'), (u'2', u'text2'), (u'3', u'text3'), (u'4', u'text4'), (u'5', u'text5')])
new_list = [(my_list[0], my_list[1], my_list[2], i[0], i[-1]) for i in my_list[3:][0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
from itertools import repeat

my_list = (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', [(u'1', u'text1'), (u'2', u'text2'), (u'3', u'text3'), (u'4', u'text4'), (u'5', u'text5')])

result = [x + y for x, y in zip(repeat(my_list[:3], len(my_list[3])), my_list[3])]

print(result)
```

Which outputs:

```
[('code', 'somet text', 'integer', '1', 'text1'), 
 ('code', 'somet text', 'integer', '2', 'text2'), 
 ('code', 'somet text', 'integer', '3', 'text3'), 
 ('code', 'somet text', 'integer', '4', 'text4'), 
 ('code', 'somet text', 'integer', '5', 'text5')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try without loop and in just one line without importing any external module or complex logic , Here is lambda approach :

```
my_list = (u'code', u'somet text', u'integer', [(u'1', u'text1'), (u'2', u'text2'), (u'3', u'text3'), (u'4', u'text4'), (u'5', u'text5')])

print((list(map(lambda v:list(map(lambda y:(y+my_list[:3]),v)),my_list[3:]))))
```

output:

```
[[('1', 'text1', 'code', 'somet text', 'integer'), ('2', 'text2', 'code', 'somet text', 'integer'), ('3', 'text3', 'code', 'somet text', 'integer'), ('4', 'text4', 'code', 'somet text', 'integer'), ('5', 'text5', 'code', 'somet text', 'integer')]]
```